# Trying to understand casting and inheritance

Tags: casting

So I'm playing around with casting...and I seem to be having issues.

```
class Rabbit implements Cloneable {
private int r;
public Rabbit(int y) {
    r= y;
}
public Object clone() {
    Object result = new Rabbit(this.r);
    return result;
}

class Bunny extends Rabbit {
private int b;
public Truck(int z) {
    super(z);
    b = z;
}
public Object clone() {
    Object result = super.clone();
    (Bunny) result).b = this.b;
    return result;
}
```

why do i keep getting a classcastexception during implementation?

Comment: You show no `main` method, so it's impossible to tell how things are being called.

Comment: You should not use the method name `clone` for your methods, since that's a pre-defined method of Object.

Comment: One guesses that your `main` created a Bunny and then called `clone` on it.  This would have cascaded to Rabbit's `clone` which would have created a new Rabbit and returned it.  Then you attempt to treat the returned Rabbit as a Bunny, hence the exception.

Comment: but if i cast the Rabbit as Bunny in the clone method, wouldn't that resolve the issue and the returned result in Bunny be a Bunny object versus a Rabbit?

Comment: A cast does not change the actual class of the object, only the declared class of the reference variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understand that in Java the "cast" notation of `(someType)` is used for three distinct (and largely unrelated) things:

1. Coercing between primitive types, as when converting an `int` to a `char`.  In this case the actual value may be modified (eg, by trimming off extraneous bits).
2. (In rare cases) To force "boxing"/"unboxing" to convert eg, `int` to `Integer`.
3. To assert a type for an object reference that is contrary to the declared type.

This third use is what you're concerned with.  It's important to understand that, unlike the other two, it does not in any way modify the runtime value of the object reference or the object itself.  Rather, it tells the compiler (and JVM "verifier") "Hey, compiler, I know that this reference is declared as being an ObjectA reference, but it really references an ObjectB -- trust me!"  So the compiler accepts that statement, but the JVM, being a untrusting soul, insists on checking at runtime.  If the referenced object is not an ObjectB (or some subclass of ObjectB) then the ClassCastException is thrown.